# How to Extract Word document text from byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am trying to get text of a Word or Excel file.However i have just access to the array of binary of this word file and i am not able to get the path of the file
so is it possible to convert binary array of Word file to string ?
i tried this code but it could not help me cause i could not get the path of the file

```
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = filePath;
        object readOnly = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            text.Append(" \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());
        }

        return text.ToString();
```

Comment: The bye of the word doesn't contain only text. you cannot do that directly. The file has a specific structure depending on the version it was made. AFAIK it is not possible for word to load from byte. You need to save to disk the byte and load it after.

Comment: If you want to do it only using the byte here's the [word doc specification version 8.1](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-DOC/%5bMS-DOC%5d.pdf) so you know what each byte mean

Comment: Are these *.doc, *.docx or *.docm files? Depending on which they are the way to access the content varies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use byte array directly, but you can find some library which can open and manipulate Word documents. Usually, these libraries can open the Word document from the stream.

I had some experience with Syncfusion and its DocIO library, which can do it. It has a free community licence, so it may be usable for testing or small teams.

You can use it something like this:

```
WordDocument doc = new WordDocument();
byte[] wordBytes = …
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(wordBytes))
{
     doc.Open(ms, FormatType.Automatic);
}
```

After you have a Word document you can extract the text from it.

Disclaimer: I have no relation with the Syncfusion company or any of its employees.

Comment: Thanks it is working just you need after it 
doc.GetText();